# browser load local file without upload

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to edit a local file without uploading to the browser?

Let's say the client has an HTML file, I want him to be able to use my site's javascript to edit the file without uploading it. Would this be possible?

Thanks.

Comment: @John - Take a look at HTML5, it *is* possible now.

Comment: @Nick: not in all browsers yet

Comment: @John - I agree, but "not in all browsers" is a  long cry from "no" :)

Comment: @Nick: not really. If you can't afford to ignore the browsers without the feature, then the answer, in effect, is "NO". Also, BTW, I get the impression that the OP would like to save the file after it's edited.

Comment: @John - I completely disagree with your analysis, if for example I'm targeting chrome users the answer is in effect, "YES"...you're making assumptions for all cases here, many will find this question and have *very* different requirements than you and I on a daily basis.

Comment: @Nick: you're being silly, I think. What kind of organization can afford to target chrome users only? And which version of Chrome? Do all versions support the needed features? Without bugs? Typically, the Internet is seen as an inclusive place, and most devs try to target a variety of browsers. Some feel ok excluding IE for religious reasons, but otherwise, most try to support a wide variety of users, not to restrict themselves to those running the latest versions of the browsers supporting HTML5.

Comment: @John - I'm currently testing an app for a buddy that will run on their corporate-wide redhat desktop install, of which all users are on Chrome...no I don't believe I am being silly. I think you're making a false assumption that *all* (instead of *most*) user bases involve windows *at all*, some are controlled, and *do* include the latest browsers (also, Chrome auto-updates even outside those environments).  You'll note I never said this was a wide-spread scenario, just that you shouldn't dismiss it altogether.  One other bad assumption you're making, not everything is for the internet.

Comment: @Nick: I said nothing about Windows. Most environments can't restrict browser vendor and version to that extent.

Comment: @John fortunately I can afford to target only non-IE users. @Nick 's answer and Pekka's comment together points me in the right direction.

Comment: @Mark: do you need to write the modified file back? Apparently, this technique doesn't do that.

Comment: @John I do need to write the file back. downloadify looks good, but it seems kind of dead. Is there a better option?

Comment: @Mark: i don't know of one. I wouldnt implement this feature yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but only in HTML5 (and only as browsers add support for it...not all do yet), [you can find the HTML5 File API here](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/).

Note that the user has to give permission to access the file, [from Section 5.9](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#requirements):

> *Once a user has given permission*, user agents should provide the ability to read and parse data directly from a **local** file programmatically.

Comment: +1 however, he can't write it back. He'd need something like downloadify for that

Answer (score 2):

Nope, that's not possible and **shouldn't be** either due to ***security*** concerns it may pose otherwise.

**Note:** This feature is there in HTML5 as pointed out by [@Nick Craver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574240/browser-load-local-file-without-upload/4574270#4574270), you *may want to go for* but you should be aware of the fact that HTML5 isn't yet supported by all browsers.

Comment: @Nick Craver: Not that early yet, HTML5?, far away :)